# How can I create a nested dictionary where first dictionary's values act as second dictionary's keys?

Tags: python, nested, tuples

pretty new to Python3.
Currently I have two dictionaries.I'd like to create a nested dictionary from these two dictionaries where first one's values act as second one's keys.

I need this nested dictionary in order to create a distance dictionary.

Here are the dictionaries I currently have. I shortened them.

First_dict = `{1: [513, 279, 582, 392, 297], 2: [297, 279, 513, 582, 392], 3: [581, 513, 582, 279, 392], 4: [513, 392, 582, 581, 279], 5: [392, 582, 513, 256, 279]}`

Second_dict = `{1: [0.6291397367847646, 0.7823399663201693, 0.8703625254182541, 1.0191414569956174, 1.0660162833624383], 2: [1.1155101452481397, 1.458507500394341, 1.7296683927743512, 1.8516961940275365, 2.0394772611422898], 3: [1.0046417248903352, 1.6138932511336632, 2.019918213435814, 2.024041235739835, 2.1045679202779155], 4: [0.8243626999510179, 1.2266312282559746, 1.2610971914206033, 1.401014162304405, 1.6046645352870748], 5: [0.9675124417465746, 1.1617482428771608, 1.3487710896578955, 1.6227371558506822, 1.6649312106185767]}`

I need to pair these values because second dictionary's values are corresponding distances of the points that are in first dictionary's values.

Here's what I want. `{1: {513: 0.6291397367847646}, {279:0.7823399663201693}, {582:0.8703625254182541},{392:1.0191414569956174}, {297: 1.0660162833624383}` (I wrote a small section, only the first key of the nested dictionary.

Here's what I have tried:

```
def dict_to_key(l):
        return tuple(sorted(l.items()))
({dict_to_key(second_dict[v]): k for k, v in first_dict.items()})
```

when I try this code, the error I get is this: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only requirement for a dictionary key is that the key is hashable. Mutable types like lists, dictionaries, and sets won’t work and result in an error like TypeError: unhashable type `list`: [1](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am sure there is a 1 liner for this, but it will not be readable, so instead this is a 3 liner.

```py
First_dict = {1: [513, 279, 582, 392, 297], 2: [297, 279, 513, 582, 392], 3: [581, 513, 582, 279, 392], 4: [513, 392, 582, 581, 279], 5: [392, 582, 513, 256, 279]}
Second_dict = {1: [0.6291397367847646, 0.7823399663201693, 0.8703625254182541, 1.0191414569956174, 1.0660162833624383], 2: [1.1155101452481397, 1.458507500394341, 1.7296683927743512, 1.8516961940275365, 2.0394772611422898], 3: [1.0046417248903352, 1.6138932511336632, 2.019918213435814, 2.024041235739835, 2.1045679202779155], 4: [0.8243626999510179, 1.2266312282559746, 1.2610971914206033, 1.401014162304405, 1.6046645352870748], 5: [0.9675124417465746, 1.1617482428771608, 1.3487710896578955, 1.6227371558506822, 1.6649312106185767]}
Third_dict = {}
for key in First_dict.keys():
    Third_dict[key] = {x:y for x,y in zip(First_dict[key],Second_dict[key])}
print(Third_dict)
```

output:

```
{1: {513: 0.6291397367847646, 279: 0.7823399663201693, 582: 0.8703625254182541, 392: 1.0191414569956174, 297: 1.0660162833624383}, 2: {297: 1.1155101452481397, 279: 1.458507500394341, 513: 1.7296683927743512, 582: 1.8516961940275365, 392: 2.0394772611422898}, 3: {581: 1.0046417248903352, 513: 1.6138932511336632, 582: 2.019918213435814, 279: 2.024041235739835, 392: 2.1045679202779155}, 4: {513: 0.8243626999510179, 392: 1.2266312282559746, 582: 1.2610971914206033, 581: 1.401014162304405, 279: 1.6046645352870748}, 5: {392: 0.9675124417465746, 582: 1.1617482428771608, 513: 1.3487710896578955, 256: 1.6227371558506822, 279: 1.6649312106185767}}
```